# How to get same ID from button that has children elements inside, prevent child element click?

Tags: reactjs

I have a button that has a background color `orange` and then children elements are marked as `red`. When i click on orange area i get the results i want (the ID of the element) but when i click on the `red` area i get no ID (or target element).

How can i wrap the children in my button so that if i click anywhere in the button i get the same ID (button element)?

```js
const Example = () => {


  return (
    <button
      id="01"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "orange", padding: "40px" }}
      onClick={e => console.log(e.target.id)}
    >
      <span
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red", padding: "20px" }}
        className="content-type"
      >
        Button One
      </span>
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I don't think anyone is expecting a solution from CSS**

But You can just add css and BOOM :

```
 pointerEvents : "none"
```

---

Please run the below code snippet, Hope it will help you:

```js
const Example = () => {
  return (
    <button
      id="01"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "orange", padding: "40px" }}
      onClick={e => console.log(e.target.id)}
    >
      <span
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red", padding: "20px" , pointerEvents : "none" }}
        className="content-type"
      >
        Button One
      </span>
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: @Marius, Glad to know, it helped :D

Answer (score 1):

i know this is solved but i think you might want to know a solution that don't need css is to use e.currentTarget.id instead of e.target.id  ,

e.currentTarget get the object where the handler is declared ( button ) no matter where the event was started .

e.target get the object where the event was started ( button if click at orange , span if click at red )

```
const Example = () => {


  return (
    <button
      id="01"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "orange", padding: "40px" }}
      onClick={e => console.log(e.currentTarget.id)}
    >
      <span
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red", padding: "20px" }}
        className="content-type"
      >
        Button One
      </span>
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

Ref : https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#bubbling

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble up. `target` is the element where the event originated from, so you can either add id's to all the children of the button (not practical), or assign the id in the callback.

```
const Example = () => {

  return (
    <button
      id="01"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "orange", padding: "40px" }}
      onClick={e => console.log("01")}
    >
      <span
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red", padding: "20px" }}
        className="content-type"
      >
        Button One
      </span>
    </button>
  );
};
```

In this simple example it doesn't seem to make much sense, but a typical usage of id's is when you map an array of data to JSX where the specific id is necessary to add/remove/update data within the array.

Something like

```
data.map(el => (
  <button
    key={id}
    id={el.id}
    style={{ backgroundColor: "orange", padding: "40px" }}
    onClick={e => callback(el.id)}
  >
    <span
      style={{ backgroundColor: "red", padding: "20px" }}
      className="content-type"
    >
      Button {el.id}
    </span>
  </button>
```